# Is the elementary work of a force frame independent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, work

(This is a classical-mechanics question)

Sorry for the trivial question. A force $\vec{f}$ doesn't depend on the frame of reference; however, the work $W$ done by $\vec{f}$ is, in general, a quantity that changes if we choose a different frame. A simple example: a body $P$ falls from an height $h$ to the ground because of its weight; in this scenario, an observer at rest on Earth will measure a linear trajectory $\gamma_1$ of length $h$, while an observer inside a rocket (it could be accelerating, doesn't matter), going straight towards the space, will observe a total distance $D > h$ percurred over a trajectory $\gamma_2$ (linear as well). We have
$$
  W_1 = \int_{\gamma_1}{\vec{w}\cdot{d\vec{r}_1}}<\int_{\gamma_2}{\vec{w}\cdot{}d\vec{r}_2} = W_2
$$
More generally, it holds, for two different frame of reference and a force

$$
  W_1 = \int_{\gamma_1}{\vec{f}\cdot{d\vec{r}_1}}\neq \int_{\gamma_2}{\vec{f}\cdot{}d\vec{r}_2} = W_2
$$
What I suspect, is that the above inequality is true only because $\gamma_1 \neq \gamma_2$, while $d\vec{r}_1 = d\vec{r}_2$. In fact, intuitively (I did not study multivariable calculus yet), the infinitesimal variation of the position vector, with respect to the $\textbf{space}$, should be the same for both the frames. Is this correct?

In other words, is the elementary work $\delta W := \vec{f} \cdot d\vec{r}$ frame independent?

(I am not assuming $\vec{f}$ constant).

Comment: I don't understand the question. In Galilean relativity neither the force nor the distance change. In special relativity both change. Work should be a scalar that everybody can agree on, no matter how they are moving. Am I missing something?

Comment: I may be wrong, but consider the following. A body is at rest on the ground. I walk for $10$ m away from the body. In my reference the body has moved for $10$ m; from an observer still, it didn't move at all.

Comment: That's an effect of "apparent motion" because you are in a non-inertial coordinate system. In inertial systems a body in motion stays in motion, i.e. without external forces (that are required to cause work) it will always move along a linear trajectory.

Comment: @flattermann the displacement changes in Galilean relativity. If I walk 10m down the length of a moving train, in which time the train moves 1000m, the station frame measures my displacement at 1010m, while the train car frame measures my displacement at 10m, and I measure my displacement at 0m.

Comment: Work is not a scalar in SR.

Comment: @Due.Berto FlatterMann’s comments here are incorrect. In Galilean relativity the force is frame-invariant but the distance is frame-variant (as shown below) so work is frame variant. In special relativity work is also frame-variant. The comments by g_s and naturallyInconsistent are correct. FlatterMann, I would again invite you to physicsforums.com where we can have a back and forth conversation to help you learn this material. Or at least ask a full question here (although I think a conversation will help more in your case).

Comment: @Dale The work performed by one system on another is not frame dependent. It is what your energy company bills you for each month. It doesn't change just because somebody flies over your house at 500 miles an hour and it's also the same in the reference frame of Mars. Whatever you may be calculating there, it is not work.

Comment: @FlatterMann I am sorry to see that you are still misunderstanding this topic. Again, please ask a question here or (preferably) start a thread on physicsforums.com. No physics definition is based on the bill from an energy company. Work is defined as the transfer of energy or as force times distance. Either way it is frame variant, as shown mathematically here and in other questions that you have commented on. You really need to stop commenting on this stuff until you learn it correctly. Again, most of the rest of what you post is good, you just have trouble with this topic.

Comment: @Dale Work is usually defined as the actually transferred amount of energy in the frame of the original system. That is why we define "energy as the ability of a system to perform work on another system", even without an actual performance of work. You are, of course, correct to say that if we perform work on a mass m by giving it kinetic energy, that kinetic energy will amount to more or less in a collision with another body depending on the new relative velocity. The change in the total energy, however, is just the work that was originally performed.

Comment: @FlatterMann do you have a reference for any professional scientific source that specifically states "in the frame of the original system" in their definition of work? You say it is "usually defined" that way, but I have never once seen such a definition. This may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: @Dale If we want "work" to mean the actual change of the internal energy of a system, then that's what it boils down to. This is how we teach energy conservation at the high school level (at least have 50 years ago). If we don't want it to mean that, though, then it will be very hard to explain to students why they even have to learn about work... it's an arbitrary quantity anyway. I would stick to "work" as an internal energy change and then treat the consequences of Galilean relativity to the term "energy" differently. Just my two cents.

Comment: @FlatterMann that’s ok, I didn’t think there actually was such a reference. Here are 5 references which do not add any restrictions regarding the frame: https://byjus.com/physics/work-energy-power/ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics) https://openstax.org/books/physics/pages/9-1-work-power-and-the-work-energy-theorem https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/work-and-energy/work-and-energy-tutorial/a/what-is-work https://www.texasgateway.org/resource/72-kinetic-energy-and-work-energy-theorem That restriction is only in your imagination. I think that is the source of your confusion

Comment: @Dale As you can see, and with absolutely no disrespect intended, the OP is confused why work changes under a simple Galilean transformation, when clearly no actual energy difference is in play. So what shall we call the invariant physical quantity here?

Comment: @FlatterMann in Galilean relativity the invariant quantity is internal energy. In special relativity it is mass

Comment: @Dale I will refrain from equating work with change in internal energy in the future. I need to come up with a better strategy to explain the concept of energy conservation to lay people, though. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the infinitesimal variation of the position vector, with respect to the space, should be the same for both the frames. Is this correct?

It is not correct. In Galilean relativity there is no privileged “space” that the laws of physics uniquely determine. If there are two Newtonian inertial reference frames, moving with uniform velocity $v$ in the $x$ direction then the transform between frames is:
$$T=t$$$$X= x + vt$$$$Y=y$$$$Z=z$$

So $$d\vec r= dx \ \hat i + dy \ \hat j + dz \ \hat k$$ $$d\vec R = dX \ \hat i + dY \ \hat j + dZ \ \hat k$$$$d\vec R=(dx + v \ dt)\ \hat i + dy \ \hat j + dz \ \hat k$$$$d\vec R=d\vec r + \vec v \ dt$$

So the elementary displacement is frame variant and thus the elementary work is also frame variant.

Comment: Thanks. What I can't seem to understand is: is $d\vec{r}$ a differential respect to time or respect to space? In the latter case, wouldn't it be $d\vec{r} = d\vec{R}$? If the former is true, then you solved my question.

Comment: @Due.Berto $d\vec r \ne d\vec R$ is a total differential

Answer (score 4):

Displacement is frame dependent, therefore integration with respect to displacement (work done on a particular body) is frame dependent. Re-obtain consistent **net** work across frames by tracking both bodies of the third-law action/reaction pair. When the velocity of both bodies in the pair is nonnegligible, both bodies' change in velocity will result in nonnegligible change in kinetic energy, even if their masses are very different and hence the change in velocity of the more massive body is very small.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by work across frames?

Comment: I mean, if Alice and Bob have a relative velocity, Alice and Bob will measure the same value for net work if and only if they measure the change in velocity of the one thing due to the "action" and the change in velocity of the other thing due to the "equal and opposite reaction".

Answer (score 2):

As already shown by @Dale, elementary displacement is frame dependent. That, in turn, makes elementary work frame dependent.

Frame dependency of work can also be show by applying the work energy theorem to different reference frames. The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

Let the initial velocity of an object in the ground (stationary) frame be $v_{i}$. To an observer in a frame moving with constant velocity $v_{i}'$ with respect to the ground frame in the same direction as the object, where $v_{i}'\lt v_{i}$ the velocity of the object for the moving observer is $v_{i}-v_{i}'$.

In the ground frame net work is done on the object so that its final velocity in that frame is $v_{f}$. In the moving frame the final velocity is $v_{f}-v_{i}'$. Then, from the work energy theorem

In the ground frame

$$W_{NET}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv_{i}^{2}$$

In the moving frame

$$W_{NET}'=\frac{1}{2}m(v_{f}-v_{i}')^2-\frac{1}{2}m(v_{i}-v_{i}')^2$$

Or

$$W_{NET}'=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv_{i}^{2}-mv_{i}'(v_{f}-v_{i})$$

Since $v_{f}\gt v_{i}$, $W_{NET}'\lt W_{NET}$ or net work done in the moving frame relative to the ground is less than the net work done in the stationary (ground) frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with this definition of work is that we are running into an energy conservation problem. If we want "work" to mean the change in total internal energy, then this is not workable. If we don't want it to mean that, then it's fine, but then the term loses its most important characteristic IMHO. Now, I am being told that my opinion is wrong, which is fine, but I would suggest to rethink the consequences on teaching introductory physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann I'm not defining work here. I'm only applying the work energy theorem as an example to show that net work depends on the reference frame.

Comment: I understand. I had this discussion with Dale before. My take on it is that one should treat mechanical work the way we treat thermodynamical work: as an internal energy change. Otherwise it becomes very hard to explain to the layman (and high schoolers) why the work of the car engine in the rest system of the driver is zero, why it's the actual amount of mechanical work performed by the engine in the rest system of the road and an insanely larger number in the rest system of the center of gravity of Andromeda. Again, just my two cents.